# IDP initiated SingleLogout with not signed LogoutRequest

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security-saml2

I have a spring boot v.5+ application which uses spring security saml.

When an idp initiated SingleLogout Request is called i get an error saying :

```
org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLStatusException: LogoutRequest is required to be signed by the entity policy
```

Is there an option to disable signing of LogoutRequest in my service provider?

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue. I tried to tweak the default value of `requireLogoutRequestSigned` property (from default true to false) in [Table 7.2. Extended metadata settings](https://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security-saml/1.0.x-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#quick-start-testing) of my SP and it worked for me. I'm using `MetadataGenerator` bean to configure this setting in spring-boot v2.1.1.RELEASE and spring-security-saml2-core v1.0.3.RELEASE.